# Finding probabilities given a density function

Tags: probability

Given the density function $f(x) = ke^{-3x}$ where $x\in\{0,\infty\}$, how would you find $k$?

Furthermore, how would one find $P(0 \leq X \leq 2)$? According to my notes, we would simply integrate the density function multiplied by $x$ from 0 to 2. Is that the way to do it?

Comment: The appropriate $k$ is the one that makes the integral from $0$ to $\infty$ equal to $1$. And no, you just integrate the density from $0$ to $2$.

Answer (score 1):

The support of the continuous random variable, $X$, is $0\leq X<\infty$.

Then by definition: $~\mathsf P(a\leq X\leq b)~=~\int\limits_a^b f(x)\operatorname d x~$  for $~0\leq a < b$ .

Also by definition also: $~\mathsf P(0\leq X<\infty) = 1$

Put this to use.